# Magick.NET and creating a hidden text watermark

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, watermark, magick.net

Is there a way to create a hidden watermark text so we can verify if our images were copied on another site in the future?  We are currently playing around with this code below but it just writes the text all over the image, instead of it being hidden and not seen.  Is there anything other then a watermark I can do to handle this situation with Magick.NET?

The below code doesn't seem to be getting 0 back on new file.

```
     using (var message = new MagickImage("label:© Events", 200, 20))
 {
     using (var image = new MagickImage(imagePath))
     {
         image.Stegano(message);
         image.Write(imageSteganoPath);

         var settings = new MagickReadSettings();
         settings.Format = MagickFormat.Stegano;
         settings.Width = 200;
         settings.Height = 20;

         using (var hiddenMessage = new MagickImage(imageSteganoPath, settings))
         {
             Assert.AreEqual(0, message.Compare(hiddenMessage, ErrorMetric.RootMeanSquared));
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: If it's hidden, and the thief screenshots your image..

Comment: This is about screen scrapping, not screenshots

Comment: Then I kinda don't understand your request; if you want to know if another website has byte-for-byte identically downloaded mikeflynn.com/img1.png and uploaded it to thiefsite.com/img2.png, you can just download it and run a byte equality compare on the two files. It doesn't matter if you put your hidden copyright in it via e.g. EXIF, the bytes themselves are proof enough. My comment implored you to think about someone stealing your image and making a visually-equivalent copy that is not byte-same by some re-encoding process e.g. screenshot, resizing, changing the format, 1 pixel change etc..

Comment: It does matter.  Our clients upload logos on our site, they can also upload those same logos on their site so your genius idea of a byte-for-byte comparison WILL NOT WORK.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying; you want to know if siteX has copied your image; download the image from siteX and compare its bytes to your bytes. Of course, if siteX belongs to the client and they also have rights to that image then don't call the police on them.. ?

Comment: You do know what I am saying.